# Rename all files in a Unix Directory with a different date format

Tags: rename

Can u please let me know how i can change all  Filenames in a Unix Directory as follows:

From : *_mmddyyyy.xls

To  : *_yyyymmdd.xls

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
ls *.xls | while read f; do
  base=${f%_*}
  mdy=${f#*_}
  mdy=${mdy%.xls}
  y=${mdy#????}
  md=${mdy%????}
  mv $f $base_$y$md.xls
done
```

or:

```
ls *.xls > old
sed 's/_\(....\)\(....\)/_\2\1/' old > new
paste old new | while read b n; do mv $b $n; done
```

Comment: I think i should stated more clearly that the filename can have one or more underscores '_' but the last underscore in the filename is followed by the date in format mmddyyyy. For eg **E-SSS_Reporting_for_Small_Groups_10012013.xls** needs to be renamed as **E-SSS_Reporting_for_Small_Groups_20131001.xls** .How can this be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in *_mmddyyyy.xls ; do mv "$i" `echo "$i" | sed -e 's/^\(.*_\)\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\(\.xls\)$/\1\4\2\3\5/'` ; done
```

Use "echo" instead of "mv" until you are sure the loop is producing the correct results -- either of us could have typos.